# Freemarker templates - Is it possible to extract a part of template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a super template which contains all possible combinations i need. Programmatically i want to extract some portions of the template and apply data - is it possible?

Is it possible to merge multiple templates and process as one template?

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract a part of a template.

If you want a super-template that is pieced together from part-templates, use [`<#include>`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html).

That way you can use the part-template directly too.